# UItextFields Data to JSON

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

i have two UItextFields, userNameTextField and passwordTextField and a UIbutton connection. I would like to have what the user typed in the userNametextField and the passwordTextField, How i can do this please ?? thanks for your answer.

```
#pragma mark - User auhtentification
-(IBAction)userAuthentificate{
    BOOL loginValid = YES;
    BOOL passwordValid = YES;   // Not specified yet

    // contrioll d'interfac__ on test login et password
    if (loginValid && passwordValid) {

    NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"login\":\"Samir\",\"password\":\"test\",\"mail\":\"test@gmail.com\"}";


        //  NSString *jsonRequest = @"{\"login\":\"Samir\",\"password\":\"test\",\"mail\":\"samir@gmail.com\",\"editor\":\"1\"}";


        NSString *request_url =@"http:.../register"; // Url WS
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:request_url];
        self.currentRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        currentRequest.delegate =self;
        NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
        [self.currentRequest appendPostData:requestData];
        [self.currentRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

        [self.currentRequest startSynchronous];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put something like this in the place of your `jsonRequest` string (the code uses the [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) framework):

```
NSDictionary *container = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [loginTextField text], @"login",
                            [passwordTextField text], @"password",
                            [mailTextField text], @"mail"];

NSString *jsonString = [container JSONRepresentation];
// don't forget to release container if not using ARC AFTER creating the NSData object
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple string replacement?

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"login\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\",\"mail\":\"%@\"}", userNameTextField.text, passwordTextField.text, emailtextField.text];
```

Comment: i would like to have the same think "jsonrequest" with the value of my loginTextField and passworftextField and emailtextField ?

Comment: I've put it all as one line for you (If I understood you correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"login\":\""%@"\",\"password\":\""%@"\",\"mail\":\"test@gmail.com\"}",userNameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];
```